# loopback postgresql fetches "id" field only

Tags: postgresql, select, loopbackjs

I try to make a project with using of loopback and remote postgresql database.
Tables are filled and I see it in pgAdmin.

I have this code:

/models/language.js

```
var loopback = require('loopback'),
 app = require('../app');


loopback.createModel('languages', {
 id: Number,
 des_id: Number,
 iso: String,
 codepage: String
})


app.model('languages', { dataSource: 'pg' });
```

(I'm not agree with concept of using one file for storing all model definitions. But I'm agree that LDL is cool! ^_^)

"loopback-explorer" successfully shows my REST's for new model. But when I try to GET something it selects only "id" fields.

```
[ { id: 1 },
  { id: 4 },
  { id: 6 },
  { id: 7 },
  { id: 8 },
  { id: 9 },
...
]
```

It counts right number of entities.

This code has no effect of fintering:

```
app.models.languages.find({
  where: {'des_id': 14360}},
 function(err, langs) {
 console.log(langs)
 });
```

I get the same amount of data as in previous output.

I tried this

```
app.models.languages.find({
    fields: {id: false}
  },
  function(err, langs) {
    console.log(langs)
  });
```

same effect.

I tried to create model without properties defenition:

```
loopback.createModel('languages', {})
```

same effect.

but

```
app.datasources.pg.discoverModelProperties('languages', function(err, props) {
  console.log(props);
})
```

shows right scheme

Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By this code:

```
loopback.createModel('languages', {
    ...
})
```

I created some object (model definition?) that wasn't used anywhere. Also creator is a base "class" *loopback* and not instanced applicataion *app*.
And this code:

```
app.model('languages', { dataSource: 'pg' });
```

created new model which available in app.models but without any schema definition. That's why I got only id-s and no other fields.

Right way:

```
var loopback = require('loopback'),
    app = require('../app');

var Langs = app.datasources.pg.createModel('languages', {
    ...
})

app.model(Langs);
```